# How to select category based on weight?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Make

- Honda
- Toyota
- Ferrari

Weight

- “Light” — Up to 500kg
- “Medium” — 500kg to 2500kg
- “Heavy” — 2500kg and higher

The application will automatically assign each vehicle a Category based on its weight.
Categories are configurable and can be changed in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual shorthand way is usually done via a case <strike>statement</strike> expression e.g.,

```
SELECT CarMake, CarModel, CarWeight,
    CASE WHEN CarWeight <= 500 THEN 'Light'
         WHEN CarWeight > 500 AND CarWeight < 2500 THEN 'Medium'
         WHEN CarWeight >= 2500 THEN 'Heavy'
         ELSE NULL END
FROM  CarList
```

However, the alternative is to have a table with weight ranges and use a join. This allows you to change the values in the table without needing to change the code e.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE CarWeights 
     (CarWeight_Name varchar(20), 
      Carweight_MinWeight int, 
      CarWeight_MaxWeight int
      );

INSERT INTO CarWeights (CarWeight_Name, CarWeight_MinWeight, CarWeight_MaxWeight) VALUES
('Light', 0, 500),
('Medium', 501, 2499),
('Heavy', 2500, 100000);  -- Note I used an arbitrary large number here as a shortcut. 

SELECT CL.CarMake, CL.CarModel, CW.CarWeight_Name
FROM  CarList CL
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CarWeights CW 
         ON CL.CarWeight >= CW.CarWeight_MinWeight 
         AND CL.CarWeight <= CW.CarWeight_MaxWeight;
```

You need to ensure you get

- Correct data types (ints, decimals, etc)
- Correct versions of >, <, >=, <= so everything fits into one (and only one) category

Note that I used a LEFT JOIN in the answer so that it will return the car makes/models even if you don't have a weight assigned to it. If you want to exclude these rows, change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: case *expression* even :)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the solution Dale and Sean I was trying with inner join group by category but that wasn't quite right